# Categorical Functional Analysis

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I've been studying functional Analysis (from Kreyszing's book, and then Brezis's book) and Category theory (from Riehl's book and Mac Lane's book) separately for one year. And I would like to study the connections between both branches, or more precisely all involving both branches.

Looking at the web, I found two articles about a categorification of Banach Space theory: [The Hitchhiker Guide to Categorical Banach Space Theory. Part I](https://www.eweb.unex.es/eweb/extracta/Vol-25-2/25J2Castillo.pdf) and [The Hitchhiker Guide to Categorical Banach Space Theory. Part II](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2110.06300.pdf).

Are they a good point to start with? What other things involving these two branches can I study, or is this approach a dead end?

I really appreciate your help and guidance.

Answer (score 2):

You should check Helemskii Lectures and Exercises on Functional Analysis. (It could be a little too introductory given your background, but does use the categorial theory language).